# Limit checkboxes with Facetwp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using FacetWP, a WordPress plug-in. It's well documented but I'm not getting the following right. I want to set a limit on the amount of checkboxes that can be selected.

You can see 3 checkboxes here. It are no default checkboxes so solutions like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gbrodzik/vVxM2/2229/

I already tried and can't get them to work properly

I've read the documentation and I got to the following script:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
?>
    <script>
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".facetwp-checkbox").click(function () {
                    if (FWP.facets['hosting_provider_naam'].length = 2) {
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php });
```

Now I can't select any checkbox so something is wrong with my if statement and I can't seem to find out what I am doing wrong.

Anybody got an idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, the comparison operator is `==` ...

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for the reply, I allready tried that. With == the selection is working again but my if statement is not because I can select all 3 checkboxes and the limit 2 is not set

Comment: Well I have no idea what that `FWP.facets` thing is supposed to be, or when that updates itself. Plus, you deviated quite a lot from the working example in the fiddle ... you are using a completely different event, for starters. Handling _clicks_ on checkboxes isn't a really good idea, that always leads to confusion whether the checked status _has_ already changed at that point, or is about to.

Comment: @CBroe, when I select for example two checkboxes and paste this code in the browser console:  FWP.facets['hosting_provider_naam'], it gets the selected values and the lenght. So I'm trying with the if statement to check if there are two selected checkboxes and then do something. The fiddle is just an example of another way I tried it. Tested those code with default checkboxes and that is working but not within my code for some reason. I think because it are not "checkboxes" but div's that act like checkboxes. Any idea how I could get it working with the fiddle and my code?

Comment: You're going to have to look into how that FacetWP actually works in more detail then. I would assume that probably has already bound a click handler of its own to these elements, so trying to stop further event propagation from your own handler that was added later on, is probably pointless to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for the help. You are probably right but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation and I allready asked the developer of the plug-in but they won't help me out either. Anyway, thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but if anyone is interested in addressing this problem with newer versions of FacetWP, I propose this solution (tested with `FacetWP 4.7`).

The logic is: whenever the `facetwp-loaded` event is triggered, check if your facet of type checkbox has at least `maxNumOptions` options selected. If yes, add the class `disabled` to all unchecked options. This class prevents the checkbox to which it is assigned from being selected.

```
if (typeof FWP !== 'undefined') {
    document.addEventListener('facetwp-loaded', function() {
        const facetName = 'hosting_provider_naam'
        if(typeof FWP.facets !== 'undefined' && typeof FWP.facets[facetName] !== 'undefined' && FWP.facet_type[facetName] === 'checkboxes') {
            const maxNumOptions = 2
            if(FWP.facets[facetName].length >= maxNumOptions) {
                let not = ''
                FWP.facets[facetName].forEach(function(facetValue) {
                    not += ':not([data-value="'+facetValue+'"])'
                })
                document.querySelectorAll('.facetwp-facet[data-name="'+facetName+'"] .facetwp-checkbox'+not).forEach(function(checkbox) {
                    checkbox.classList.add('disabled')
                })
            }
        }       
    })
}
```